# Notation in identification function

Tags: notation

The notation I have does not fall with the notation in the wiki link and I want to see I understood.

Can I expand the following [idicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function):
$$ 1\{x\leq 0\}x$$
in the following way?
$$1 =
  \begin{cases}
    x       & \quad x\leq 0\\
    0  & \quad \text{else }\\
  \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat confusing. Do you mean indicator function?

If so, then $1\{x\leq0\}x$ would be more conveniently written (if I understand what you mean) as $\mathbf{1}_{x\leq0}(x)\cdot x$; $\mathbf{1}$ to stress that this is not multiplication by unity, the subscript $_{x\leq0}$ again to stress that this is an indicator function, and evaluated at $(x)$ since the indicator function is a function.

Having said this, $$\mathbf{1}_{x\leq0}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\leq0\\0&\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$$
so that $\mathbf{1}_{x\leq0}(x)\cdot x=x$ if $x\leq0$ and $\mathbf{1}_{x\leq0}(x)\cdot x=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Oops. sorry, and yes I do mean indicator. edited.

Answer (score 1):

The notation you mention seems to be using the [Iverson bracket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket):
$$
 [x\le0] =
  \begin{cases}
    1,       & \quad x\leq 0\\
    0,  & \quad \text{otherwise }\\
  \end{cases}
$$
Then the function you want is $f(x) = [x\le0] x$.